# Build confusion matrix for multiclass multilabel classification

Tags: confusion-matrix, multilabel-classification

I would like to build a confusion matrix for multiclass multilabel classification to calculate then precision, recall and F1.
One idea is to build it from all combinations which come in training and test set, e.g.

```
       A1 A2A3 A1A3
A1     x    x   x
A2A3   x    x   x 
A1A3   x    x   x
```

The other idea is to build it like for a simple label classification, but use double values for values ​​of the matrix, e.g.

```
       A1     A2     A3
A1   double double double
A2   double double double
A3   double double double
```

the question in this case is how to calculate this values meaningful?

Has somebody experience with building of such matrices? Which version is more rational?
If there is some other way to build such confusion matrix, would be glad to hear it from you.

Greetings, Andriy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it also interests somebody, here is how it works for me:
I used first idea and calculated label based measures due to description from: Gj. Madjarov, et al., An extensive experimental comparison of methods for multi-label learning, Pattern
Recognition (2012).

The corresponding code can be found at dkpro-tc (DKPro Text Classification Framework) in evaluation module.